# Fixed point iteration method with parameter

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I have these iterative methods:

1. $x_{i+1} = (1−k)x_i+1$
2. $x_{i+1} = (2−kx_i)x_i$

$0 < k < 1$, converging to $1/k$

I have to determine for which values ​​of $x_0$ the sequences generated by the two methods
converge and determine the order of convergence.
I pretty understood how fixed point iteration method works but how to proceed with the *k* parameter?. Thanks.

Comment: "How do I proceed with $k$?" - what is it that you need to do?

Comment: i mean, what is the difference if there is a parameter?

Comment: Well, perhaps you can check three cases:$k<0$; $0<k<1$ and $k>1$ and see what happens in each case. You can just select a value that you want to try, for ex. $k=\frac{1}{2}$ in the second case.

Comment: okay, thank you, the exercise says 0<k<1 so i think i can use only that case.